# Find elements that are found in every person order

Tags: sql, sqlite

Having such table, for every ID I need to write SQL query to find those materials that are in every order for specific ID

| ID | ORDER_ID | MATERIAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'ID1' | 12 | 'wood' |
| 'ID1' | 12 | 'gold' |
| 'ID1' | 12 | obsidian' |
| 'ID1' | 68 | 'wood' |
| 'ID1' | 68 | 'gold' |
| 'ID1' | 68 | 'obsidian' |
| 'ID1' | 68 | bedrock' |
| 'ID2' | 138 | 'glass' |
| 'ID2' | 138 | 'sandstone' |
| 'ID2' | 138 | 'wood' |
| 'ID2' | 139 | 'glass' |
| 'ID2' | 139 | 'sandstone' |
| 'ID2' | 139 | 'wood' |
| 'ID2' | 139 | 'concrete' |

The result must be:

| ID | MATERIAL |
| --- | --- |
| 'ID1' | 'wood' |
| 'ID1' | 'gold' |
| 'ID1' | 'obsidian' |
| 'ID2' | 'glass' |
| 'ID2' | 'sandstone' |
| 'ID2' | 'wood' |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select m.ID, m.MATERIAL
from (
    select id, MATERIAL, count(*) c
    from table
    group by id, MATERIAL
)m
inner join (
    select id, count(distinct ORDER_ID) c
    from table
    group by ID
)o
on o.ID = m.ID
and o.c = m.c
```